# 1 of 3 services running wamp 3.1.0....not 1 of 2...but 1 of 3...WTH

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm running Windows 7 (32bit) with WAMP server 3.1.0.

I only downloaded WAMP and installed it, but it shows 1 of 3 services running. ..i tried checking online for solution....but everyone says 1 of 2 or 2 of 3.....its like no one ever had my problem....if you know what this is please tell me....or atleast tell me what the three services are?.....once again i only installed wamp only not installed apache or oracle database hoping wamp does it for me...

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got this same kind of problem, **below are the following steps** I took to get it done.

1. Make sure firewall is not blocking apache app. **goto control panel>allow an app through windows firewall>change settings>allow another app>browse this directory "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin" and click on httpd.exe**
2. The default port for apache is 80 and its most time being occupied by another application(e.g Skype). so its important you set your apache to use another port. **click on wamp icon on the system tray>apache>http.conf, then look for all the lines of code that include :80 (it should about three different lines), and change them to :8080 (or any number you prefer apart from :80)**
3. Once that is done, click on wamp icon on the system tray. The three services needed to run are the Apache Service, MySQL, and MariaDB service. click on each of them as follow

a.  apache>service administration 'wampapache'>if start/resume service is 
      enabled, click it otherwise, click on install service first, and then 
      click start service

b.  MySQL>service administration 'wampmysqld'>if start/resume service is 
      enabled, click it otherwise, click on install service first, and then 
      click start service

c.  MariaDB>service administration 'wampmariadb'>if start/resume service is enabled, click it otherwise, click on install service first, and then click start service

4. Lastly **Restart all services**. And there you go... Let me know if it helps. it solved it for me

Comment: for me `change settings` is disabled.

Comment: Hello Zeeshan Ahmad Khalil, the essence of change settings button is to enable "allow another app" button. so if the allow another app button is enabled. You're good to go

Comment: sometimes MySQL is causing the issue and by restaring Host Network Service, problem is solved. run following commands in administration mode in windows :

`net stop hns`
`net start hns`

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have "Controlled folder access" enabled in windows defender. I had that one that blocked access.

Answer (score 0):

On your computer, type services and go to WAMP

Enable this service by right-clicking on wampapache64/wampapache32, as the case may be. Then select properties and select Manual. Afterwards, select start to enable the service.

Remember to log out of skype before starting the WAMP server again and see the magic of Green.

All the best !

Answer (score 0):

For my case I did what Akinsam indicated but **MariaDB** dosen't start so I did the following:

in **my.ini** I modified the port (**port=3306** to 3307). and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

please dont stress yourself, just unstall WAMP,download VC-redist.x64.exe ensure it is the latest version that you downloaded, install the VC_redist.x64.exe, then install your WAMP, and all will be running........

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did this:
Unstall wampserver, install vc-redist

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Restart, and finally, re install wamp.